# thymeleaf url syntax for absolute url

Tags: thymeleaf, birt

I want to make `thymeleaf` url with `th:href` that produce this url (for my birt report)

http://localhost:8081/birt/frameset?__report=report/bordereau_emission.rptdesign&__title=BordereauEmission&__locale=fr_FR&__format=html&__masterpage=true&IdBE=23

Where &__paramName=value is a param=value in birt report url.

I tried below but it gave me parsing exception:

```
<td><a href="listebebrouillons.html" th:href="@{http://localhost:8081/birt/frameset?__report=report/bordereau_emission.rptdesign&__title=Bordereau Emission&__locale=fr_FR&__format=html&__masterpage=true&IdBE=${bordereauEmission.idBe}}">Visualiser</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<a th:href="@{http://localhost:8081/birt/frameset(
  '\_\_report'='report/bordereau_emission.rptdesign',
  '\_\_title'='Bordereau Emission',
  '\_\_locale'='fr_FR',
  '\_\_format'='html',
  '\_\_masterpage'='true',
  IdBE=${bordereauEmission.idBe}
)}">Visualiser</a>
```

`__` has special meaning in thymeleaf.  It signals a [Thymeleaf preprocessing expression](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

Comment: Thanks for your help. It works fine. I didn't know that __ has special meaning in thymeleaf.